# I am getting this error when i run my flutter project on ios simulator:-ProcessException: Process timed out:

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error message in my visual studio code terminal on flutter when I run my project on the ios simulator

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                        89.1s
Xcode build done.                                           470.2s
ProcessException: Process timed out:

Command: /usr/bin/env xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Debug -quiet -workspace 
Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner
 BUILD_DIR=/Users/sai/FlutterSDK/Projects/Todolist/App/Todolist/build/ios -sdk 
 iphonesimulator -arch x86_64
   SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/88/w77bfft52rv76y7f9skrrzk40000gq/T/flutter_tools.6EpPE0/ 
   flutter_build_log_pipe.
   7KmLr9/pipe_to_stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO - 
   showBuildSettings
```

Do you know what is causing this error.....let me know...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i have figured out what is causing this issue,This happens when you update xcode or android studio Avd or any tool you use with flutter to fix this Use `Flutter upgrade` in your general terminal and go to visual studio code and run `Flutter clean` and run `flutter run` if you face any other issues let me know......